# cocoa sheet is not modal

Tags: cocoa, focus, modal-dialog

I can't figure out why the sheet is not modal and the focus is still on the main window.

```
- (IBAction) showSheet:(NSWindow*)window
```

{
    // User has asked to see the dialog. Display it.

```
    if (!_clientsDialog)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"clientsDialog" owner: self];
        [NSApp beginSheet:self.clientsDialog
           modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate]window]
            modalDelegate: self
           didEndSelector: NULL
              contextInfo: NULL];
```

}

Comment: try adding a log message to see if sheet (self.clientsDialog) is NULL...

Comment: How, what is the method?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.clientDialog); place this line in the top of the showSheet method. If it writes (null) you have a problem with the sheet connection.

Comment: The sheet opens but the focus is on the textfield on the back window and is not possible with click to make focus on the sheet.But in same time i can click the close button to the sheet.The log returns: <NSWindow: 0x10067d9f0>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method works for me:

Header File:

```
- (IBAction)showSheet:(id)sender;
```

Method file:

```
- (void)showSheet:(id)sender {

    if (! _clientsDialog)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"clientsDialog" owner: self];

    [NSApp beginSheet: _clientsDialog
       modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate: self
        didEndSelector: NULL
            contextInfo: NULL];
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** You need to have a *Title Bar* on your window. Otherwise Controls won't work.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe that is this!Now everything works!Thanks a lot, really!

Comment: In the top of my answer there is 2 arrows. One up and One down. The up arrow is giving a point, you should do this to vote for this answer. If the question is yours there is also an empty accept image. Click it to accept the answer (it turns green when you have accepted).